# Application-wide menu bar in JavaFX 2.1?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, menubar

The [JavaFX 2.1 Release Notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/release_notes_2-1/jfxpub-release_notes_2-1.htm) states that this release includes,

- UI enhancements, including controls for Combo Box, Stacked Chart, and application-wide menu bar.

What does the "application-wide menu bar" mean? What does it imply?
Looked for UI Components but could not find any reference to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the comment refers to the new JavaFX 2.1 ability to set a menu bar to act as a system level application menu bar.  For example, on Mac, it would be the menu bar at the top of the screen.

I think the added property is [MenuBar.useSystemMenuBarProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html#useSystemMenuBarProperty).

Windows (and some Linux window managers) don't have the same concept, so I don't think the property does anything on those platforms.

Comment: I could not verify your statement but I assume you are right :)

Comment: Verified it works on Mac OS X 10.8.3 with JRE 1.7.0_10. Thanks @jewelsea!